# How to format Time stamp string "201804122359+0530" (yyyyMMddHHmmZ) to normal "DD MM yyyy HH:mm" in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, datetime, timestamp

I am doing cordova web application. I am getting time stamp like "201804122359+0530" from soap web service. I am unable to format to standard time format using these methods(str_date is variable of string time stamp)-

1-method - its throwing invalid date error

```
$scope.current_time = new Date(str_date);
```

2-method-  this also throwing invalid date error

```
var formatted_date = $filter('date')(str_date,'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss');
```

So, I am unable to format using these methods. please give me any other method to format date in angular js.

Comment: I recommend you to use `moment.js`

Comment: Iam not sure why it is working, but just Date(str_date) without new is working

Comment: you could try [`moment("201804122359+0530", "YYYYMMDDHHmmZ")`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

Comment: I used this moment- angular-momentjs.js and also i am getting invalid date error, code- $scope.strtime = $moment(value.time).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix this problem using moment. Add moment.min.js file in your lib folder and

```
     $scope.strtime = moment(str_date,"YYYYMMDDHHmmZ").format("HH");
```

I need only hour and if you want any other format you can change.

Answer (score -2):

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
function onDeviceReady() {
    console.log(navigator.globalization.getDatePattern);
}

//or//

var currentdate = new Date(); 
var datetime =  currentdate.getDate() + "/"
                + (currentdate.getMonth()+1)  + "/" 
                + currentdate.getFullYear() + " @ "  
                + currentdate.getHours() + ":"  
                + currentdate.getMinutes() + ":" 
                + currentdate.getSeconds();
```

## IT'S WORKING ##

Comment: I have time stamp from server . I am not formatting local time

Comment: I can confirm. your code does not work. If you pass the string that Alexander provided like so: `new Date('201804122359+0530')` you get an error `Invalid Date`. new Date() does not properly format that type of string.